# Excel populate cell based on match of two other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm sure this has been answered already but, frankly, I don't understand what I've seen.

I have a workbook with two sheets in.

Sheet A looks like

```
Promocode Campaign    
AAABBBCCC    
CCCFFFRRR     
AAABBBCCC    
AAABBBCCC    
CCCFFFRRR    
DDDFFFTTT
```

Sheet B looks like

```
Promocode    Campaign

AAABBBCCC    ENERGY    
CCCFFFRRR    CLIMATE    
DDDFFFTTT    OCEANS
```

I would like to autopopulate the Campaign column in Sheet A based on a lookup of the data in sheet B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple `VLOOKUP()`.

In your column B on Sheet A, put this and drag down:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,'Sheet B'!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: OK, thank you that works. Can I ask that you expand on it though slightly please? I don't understand the element A2:B4. I get that A2-A4 is what we're matching against, but how does A2:B4 provide both the lookup range and the returned value?

Comment: @Patrick - See [this page](https://exceljet.net/things-you-should-know-about-vlookup). Basically, VLOOKUP works by taking a value you want to find (`A2`'s value), and look in a table (`Sheet B's A2:B4` range).  When it finds `A2` value in the **first** column (`A`), it will then return the value in that same row, in the `2`nd column of your table.  That's what the `, 2, ` is doing in that formula.  It says "return the value in the second column of my table".

Comment: @Patrick - FYI I (and I would say most others) consider `VLOOKUP()` one of your essential formulas to use.  So, learn it, learn it well!  ...then learn my preferred [`Index/Match`](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) :P